# Is there a function that returns the file a user-defined class is defined in?

Tags: python, class

I tried using `inspect.getfile()`, but it did't work

```
from inspect import getfile

class A: pass

getfile(A.__class__)
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classtest.py", line 5, in <module>
    getfile(A.__class__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 653, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <module 'builtins' (built-in)> is a built-in class
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile: Return the name of the (text or binary) file in which an object was defined. This will fail with a ***TypeError* if the object is a built-in module, class, or function**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is already a class. `A.__class__` in Python 3 returns its meta class, which is `type` from the `'builtins'` module.

Save this as a .py file and run with Python:

```python
from inspect import getfile

class A: pass

print(getfile(A))
```

You will receive similar error if you copy & paste above code in a Python terminal. Because in a terminal `class A` is defined in module `'__main__'`, which is also considered as a built-in module in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following code to a file say in the current directory (`/home/jimbob/test/` in this example) called `example.py`

```
class MyExample:
    pass
```

Then go to your python interpretter:

```
In [1]: from example import MyExample

In [2]: import inspect

In [3]: inspect.getfile(MyExample)
Out[3]: '/home/jimbob/test/example.py'
```